# UWP Compile with .NET Native tool chain checkbox disabled

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Hi could somebody help me. After I updated my windows 10 to version 1809
my vs2017 disable the Compile with .Net Native tool chain. I cannot debug my UWP project. How can I enable it again? Any suggestion I can try?

[image: HELP]

Comment: Please check the `Configuration` in the above screenshot, the parameter is `Debug` in my side. I can't get Active(Debug .NET Native).  Please inspect `Debug .NET Native` in your configuration (build - > Configuration Manager).

Comment: If you switch to Debug configuration , the issue still exit. please try to repair the Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried to make a new blank project and inspect the build option?

Comment: Hi mr. Nico Zhu , I tried all the configuration and repair the vs2017 still  the .NET Native tool chain is disable. This happen after I update to windows 10 ver. 1809. Is this a bug update of windows 10? Do they have patch update to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Our windows is 1809, but the issue not happen in my side, have your tried to run your project in other 1809 device?

Comment: Have you tried add `<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>` in your proj file?